# Does a WiFi client vary the strength of the signal it emits?

Tags: router, wireless, ieee-802.11

I am using a metal container to dampen my WiFi router in the hope of reducing its radiation health risks.

I'm wondering if the client device might increase its own emitted signal strength to compensate for the weakened RSSI it detects?

If so then my effort to dampen the signal may have the opposite effect.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about consumer-grade devices and hosts/servers are off-topic here. You could try to ask this question on [su]. Also, there have been many studies, and there are no reported health risks. In any case, you are exposed to full-strength Wi-Fi in just about any store you go to, and most other buildings too.

Comment: Question is moved here:
https://superuser.com/questions/1681001/does-a-wifi-client-vary-the-strength-of-the-signal-it-emits

Answer (score 1):

WiFi uses considerably less transmitting power (<100 mW) than cellular phones (up to 8 W). The radiation health risks are accordingly much lower to non-existent (in comparison to radiation from other nearby sources).

Some portable devices may reduce power even when actively transmitting actively when the connection is good enough, but there's no standard.

Shielding your WAP/wireless router causes all connections to deteriorate, so eventually less efficient codes may be used as fallback, lengthening the transmissions and potentially increasing "exposure" (see above). Accordingly, your effort may cause the opposite effect you intend.

If you're serious about reducing stray radiation you should consider abandoning wireless altogether and using shielded twisted-pair cabling throughout. And of course stay clear of cell phones.

If you cannot get rid of wireless technology, make sure that your WAP/wireless router is always as close to the mobile devices as possible, making the transmissions most efficient.